# SMSLib. Service.getInstance().stopService() doesn't work

Tags: java, smslib

Im using SMSlib library to send sms from USB 3G Modem ZTE MF180.
I tried to use SendMessage.java class to test my modem, so I duplicated sms sending code - so in theory I was expecting to get 2 sms.

```
OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
    SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM6", 115200, "ZTE", "MF180");        
    gateway.setInbound(true);
    gateway.setOutbound(true);
    gateway.setSimPin("");
    gateway.setSmscNumber("+79037011111");
    Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
    Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
    Service.getInstance().startService();
    OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("79213533296", "Hello world!");
    Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
    Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
```

OutboundNotification outboundNotification2 = new OutboundNotification();

```
    SerialModemGateway gateway2 = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM6", 115200, "ZTE", "MF180");
    gateway2.setInbound(true);
    gateway2.setOutbound(true);
    gateway2.setSimPin("");
    gateway2.setSmscNumber("+79037011111");
    Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification2);
    Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway2);
    Service.getInstance().startService();
    OutboundMessage msg2 = new OutboundMessage("79213533296", "Оповещение о событии ");
    Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg2);
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
```

I get the first SMS and then falls exception:

org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.PortInUseException: org.smslib
It seems, like Service.getInstance().stopService() method doesn't works. But I dont know what to do.

Comment: I'm confused by "Service.getInstance(). setOutboundMessageNotification()" what if you were sending messages from different threads? I suppose you would only do that setup once and keep the service running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your're trying to create a new SerialModemGateway to the same COM port, which isn't doable - only one process/service can have a com port open at the same time.

Make sure you stop the first one before creating another by doing `gateway.stopGateway()`

Though you don't really need to set up and tear down the SerialModemGateway and stop/start the service every time, just create a new message and send it using the existing gateway and service you have opened.

Comment: How can I update gateway settings, Incase if I modified the Gateway settings like port or manufacturer?